# How to apply autofill using Apache POI for java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a formula in G4 and want to autofill that formula to G1000.
Manually, we simply autofill it using the AutoFill (By Pulling it down)

How to do that using AutoFill in Apache POI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not yet supported.. by Apache POI !